# Current Amplifier Design

Tags: mosfet, current, amplifier, bjt

I need to design a current amplifier.

I'm sending a PWM signal from 0 to 5V that needs to be converted to 60mA at the maximum (so 5V). I am having trouble figuring out how to design this with either a BJT or MOSFET. I understand how both of them work except for the datasheets are confusing sometimes.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the current flowing through?

Comment: The current from PWM? It is coming from a microcontroller and has not been set yet, it depends on my circuit which I am designing. So technically I can set it to what I want right? I am trying to keep that draw low though.

Comment: I was not clear. What are you trying to push the converted 0-60mA through?

Comment: The 0 to 60mA needs to drive an optoisolator, so an IR LED. Which I do not know the resistance of as of right now, but lets say its small so 20 Ohms?

Comment: A 100 ohm resistor is a fine, and dependable, voltage-to-current converter.

Comment: Can you elaborate? 100 ohm resistor where in the circuit?

Comment: 60mA sounds like abs max. But IR couplers are about 5 ohms above 1.2V

Comment: It's just a switch with very loose requirements defined by V drop over R

Comment: Do we need to beg the OP for a schematic or at least a diagram? His question and design layout are not clear. "This opto on this board talks to this opto on this board." Clear as mud to me.

Comment: Eric's design team has yet to learn how to write design specs.

Comment: No clear specs, but consider PWM RC DAC feeding setpoint of active current source.

Comment: I did not receive correct information about how much current needs to be sent, so my design has now changed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you want to use a transistor for this. Yes, a transistor is an amplifier, but maybe not in the sense you're imagining, hence your confusion when it comes to reading the datasheets.

I will give you the circuit you need to use the transistor in this application. I recommend building it, and then discovering through experimentation why it's not a great choice for this application. Primarily, the amplification ratio (called the "gain") is hard to control in an open loop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkjwSN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All you need to do is size R1 such that at 5V, enough base current flows to allow 60mA of collector current to flow. Use these two formulas:

$$
i_b = \frac{5V - 0.7V}{R1}
$$
$$
i_c = i_b\beta
$$

where \$i_b\$ is the base current, \$5V\$ is the amplitude of the PWM, \$0.7V\$ is the diode drop across the base-emitter junction, \$i_c\$ is the collector current and \$\beta\$ is the BJT gain.

Re-arranging gives:

$$
R1 = \frac{(5V - 0.7V)\beta}{i_c}
$$

So say your \$\beta\$ is 100, and your desired \$i_c\$ is 60mA, then \$R1\$ would be about \$7200\Omega\$.

When your PWM duty is 100%, the BJT will allow 60mA to flow. When it is at 50%, it will allow 60mA for 50% of the time, and 0mA for the other 50%, giving an average of 30mA.

In theory at least. In practice you might find it a little wilder than that, at which point you might be tempted to use something like an opamp in a current source topology instead.

Comment: +1 for rational thinking. I would add a resistor from base to ground just so base cannot float, or R1 would have to be a very high value. Temp changes will have the beta drift like crazy, but I did mention a servo loop to the OP. Me thinks he will have to work his way up to that level.

Comment: Ok thank you for the drawing, turns out that I just need a MOSFET.. The optocoupler was not my part of the design so he said he needed 60mA but turns out we need 10mA... We are just going to drive the optocoupler with the PWM signal current.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a 4N33 opto-coupler, or the many that are like it. Drive pin 1 with a 1 K ohm resistor and ground pin 2. Use pin 5 to drive a 2N2222 NPN transistor base to boost the current, as the 4N33 and most opto-couplers cannot handle 60 mA as a load. Pin 3 is not used. Pin 6 sets the gain, but you can leave it open or connect it to pin 4 with a 10 K to 470 K resistor. The higher the value, the more gain the opto-coupler has.

The the 2N2222 emitter is your output, which floats, so you have no ground loops possible. I was going to post a simple design schematic, but the library has no opto-couplers at this time.

If you want precise control then a servo-loop is needed to measure the output current and keep it to a setting of your choice.

Comment: The optocoupler is already chosen. I will find out which one it is and post right away, but for now I think we can assume it's low resistance.           The design right now has the optocoupler on a different PCB. My PCB receives a PWM signal (0V to 5V) and then sends 0mA to 60mA to another PCB that has the optocoupler on it, then after the optocoupler is ground.

Comment: Ok. I should have waited until you posted a schematic first. I may delete my answer if it is of no good. Our answers maybe off track until you supply a schematic or a block diagram.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGvCmQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>